# How to mock a request when unit testing a service in grails

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, spock

I am trying to unit test a service that has a method requiring a request object.

```
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder as RCH

class AddressService {

    def update (account, params) {
        try {
            def request = RCH.requestAttributes.request
            // retrieve some info from the request object such as the IP ...
            // Implement update logic
        } catch (all) { 
            /* do something with the exception */ 
        }
    }
}
```

How do you mock the request object ?

And by the way, I am using Spock to unit test my classes.

Thank you

Answer (score 8):

This code seems to work for a basic unit test ([modified from Robert Fletcher's post here](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/cannot-mock-request-in-testing-controller-tp1338897p1338898.html)):

```
void createRequestContextHolder() {
    MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest()
    request.characterEncoding = 'UTF-8'

    GrailsWebRequest webRequest = new GrailsWebRequest(request, new MockHttpServletResponse(), ServletContextHolder.servletContext)
    request.setAttribute(GrailsApplicationAttributes.WEB_REQUEST, webRequest)

    RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(webRequest)
}
```

It can be added as a function to your standard Grails unit test since the function name does not start with "test"... or you can work the code in some other way.

Answer (score 7):

One simple way to mock these, is to modify the meta class for `RequestContextHolder` to return a mock when `getRequestAttributes()` is called.

I wrote up a simple spec for doing this, and was quite surprised when it didn't work! So this turned out to be a quite interesting problem. After some investigation, I found that in this particular case, there are a couple of pitfalls to be aware of.

1. When you retrieve the request object, `RCH.requestAttributes.request`, you are doing so via an interface `RequestAttributes` that does not implement the `getRequest()` method. This is perfectly fine in groovy if the returned object actually has this property, but won't work when mocking the `RequestAttributes` interface in spock. So you'll need to mock an interface or a class that actually has this method.
2. My first attempt at solving 1., was to change the mock type to `ServletRequestAttributes`, which does have a `getRequest()` method. However, this method is final. When stubbing a mock with values for a final method, the stubbed values are simply ignored. In this case, `null` was returned.

Both these problems was easily overcome by creating a custom interface for this test, called `MockRequestAttributes`, and use this interface for the Mock in the spec.

This resulted in the following code:

```
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder

// modified for testing
class AddressService {

    def localAddress
    def contentType

    def update() {
        def request = RequestContextHolder.requestAttributes.request
        localAddress = request.localAddr
        contentType = request.contentType
    }
}
```

---

```
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestAttributes
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest

interface MockRequestAttributes extends RequestAttributes {
    HttpServletRequest getRequest()
}
```

---

```
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder
import spock.lang.Specification

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest

class MockRequestSpec extends Specification {

    def "let's mock a request"() {
        setup:
        def requestAttributesMock = Mock(MockRequestAttributes)
        def requestMock = Mock(HttpServletRequest)
        RequestContextHolder.metaClass.'static'.getRequestAttributes = {->
            requestAttributesMock
        }

        when:
        def service = new AddressService()
        def result = service.update()

        then:
        1 * requestAttributesMock.getRequest() >> requestMock
        1 * requestMock.localAddr >> '127.0.0.1'
        1 * requestMock.contentType >> 'text/plain'
        service.localAddress == '127.0.0.1'
        service.contentType == 'text/plain'

        cleanup:
        RequestContextHolder.metaClass = null
    }

}
```